# Slack and Salesforce Integration

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

I was trying to integrate Slack and Salesforce. For this I was looking for the app in the Salesforce AppExchange, but I am unable to find it. Could anyone provide me a URL for this app - Salesforce for Slack in the AppExchange.
This will really help!

Comment: note there are separate apps `Service Cloud for Slack` and `Sales Cloud for Slack` as well

Answer (score 0):

The AppExchange url for `Salesforce for slack` can be found [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFo7gUAD&_ga=2.157424696.327926499.1706617272-574932904.1638506941)

Process for installation and configuration is describe [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/partners/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3A00000aWRpTUAW)

Please refer [this](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/227838227-Salesforce-apps-for-Slack) article before using the app since its a private listing.

Comment: Thanks ! I will give it a try

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if the answer helped you.